# SQL Server 2014 vs SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am looking for document that compare `SQL Server 2014` editions. and have new features, commands and services in `SQL Server 2014` vs `SQL Server 2012`.

Comment: A Google search for **SQL Server 2014 vs SQL Server 2012** provides exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find summarized and interesting information here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/cansql/archive/2014/04/14/sql-server-2014-benefits-of-upgrading-from-sql-server-2005-2008-2008r2-and-2012.aspx